# Have trouble implementing Low Search using Expresso Store

Tags: add-on, ee2, expresso-store, low-search

I'm trying to implement Low Search for the first time and I'm struggling with how you integrate it.

I don't fully understand what Collections are and How I should use them. I'm using the expresso store and have a number of categories for products. I would like to have the ability to show product based on price, and some other criteria. Do I create a collection for each product section or product type?

Secondly I have a page that shows products right now. I would like to use the same page to display the results in the same manor. Once I have create the form inputs, checkboxes, etc., how do I set it up to make the search based on all selected criteria?

Secondly, How do I display the results. I have seen the example on the product page, but I don't understand how I implement my results page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is some initial code to get started. What am I doing wrong?

```
{exp:low_search:form collection="central_vacuums" search_mode="all" result_page="products/index"}

                 <select name="range:regular_price">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value=";99">$0.00 - $99.99</option>
                    <option value="100;199">$100.00 - $199.99</option>
                    <option value="200;399">$200.00 - $399.99</option>
                    <option value="400;799">$400.00 - $799.99</option>
                    <option value="800;">$800.00 and over</option>
                </select>

                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

            {/exp:low_search:form}


            {exp:low_search:results limit="10"}
                {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                    <p>{regular_price}</p>
                {/exp:store:product}
            {/exp:low_search:results}
```

Comment: Before adding a proper answer, see if the explanation I gave here helps you with at least part of your question: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1157/172

Comment: At the moment Store is not Low Search or Super Search compatible so you would need to use the Store Search Feature https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/tags/search.html to search product prices and modifiers.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm going to read through all of the info provided. Justin... Is there a way to create a dropdown with price ranges and have a submit button to filter the results with Expresso Store? There example doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Low. Is there any way to work with Expresso store data?

Comment: I've never worked with Store, so I'm not sure. But if they save their data in the `exp_channel_data` table, then it should be supported. If not, then they could use the Low Search API and/or extension hooks to add support for it.

Comment: We only Store some data in the `exp_channel_data` table. Adding the search API and/or extension hooks is on the list of things to add for a future release

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at Low Search Store. This adds compatibility with Expresso Store to Low Search - https://github.com/low/low_search_store

:)

Answer (score 1):

Low Search cannot be fully implemented with Exp:resso Store data at this time.

Comment: Anna do you have a reference for that? Might be worth adding so that if the situation on compatibility changes later, future SE users will be able to find out...

Comment: I think it's true, though I don't there is any documented list of third party add-ons which support Low Search. I haven't personally used Low search, but Store does keep most product data in separate tables, so Low Search support would probably need to be explicitly added to Store.

Comment: Justin Long says in his comment above that Store isn't compatible with Low Search.