# Low Search - Can you search multiple collections in one search?

Tags: low-search

Assuming that some collection fields are the same, can you search multiple collections in one search/search form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Treat the collection parameter as the channel parameter. Multiple collections are searchable, even if the collection fields are different.

Comment: Read more about the concept of Low Search in the Primer: http://gotolow.com/blog/a-low-search-primer and this EESE answer: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1157/172